# A new algorithm for determining if a number is prime or not

Tags: algorithms, number-theory, primes

This approach has been on my mind for quite some time. I did come up with it myself, I searched some methods for determining prime numbers but never came across anything similar to this.

```
import math
n = int(input())
def is_prime(n):
    x=n
    i= 2
    while(x>i):
        if n%i==0:
            return False
        x = math.ceil(n/i)
        i+=1
    return True
print(is_prime(n))
```

Can anyone tell me if this method already exists and can someone give me its time complexity.

Comment: @Akash Your algorithm is pretty good. I do not think I have seen it exactly.

Comment: You may want to exclude the case $n=1$. Or `n = int(input("Please enter an integer greater than 1\n"))`

Comment: There are code that uses `n >= i * i` as the condition for the `while` loop. I would consider they are similar to your code.

Comment: Your function `is_prime` is logically equivalent to the following simplified version. `def is_prime(n):
    i = 2
    while (n >= (i +1) * (i - 1)):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
        i += 1
    return True`.

Comment: Such a primality test for small numbers has certainly been programmed by million people. So don't expect to come up with something new that easily.

Answer (score 1):

Very sorry, but this is just a variant of the successive divisions method, the most basic of all, that a simple Web search would have shown you. Nothing new.

Note that trying all integers instead of the odd numbers is a little waste. Also, divisions are more costly than multiplies, so the test $i^2<n$ would be better (even better to precompute $\sqrt n$).

Comment: Though I admit my approach is very basic, I don't find it very similar to the successive divisions method. Here all I'm doing is reducing the iterations. The i*i method is more similar to this approach.

Comment: @AkashRam: it is 100% successive divisions, and you are NOT "reducing the iterations". You just perform $\sqrt n$ of them like in any *decent* successive divisions method.

Answer (score 0):

You are testing whether n is divisible by consecutive i, for 2 ≤ i up to some limit. You want that limit to be small, to avoid unnecessary tests. Usually people start at their very first attempt with trying 2 ≤ i ≤ n-1 which does roughly n divisions is n is a prime.

If n is not prime, then it has a smallest prime factor i and another factor j ≥ i. (j isn't smaller than i because i is the smallest prime factor). The smallest number that has i as its smallest prime factor is i * i, so you only need to test numbers i such that i*i ≤ n. You do that quite accurately, so you do about $\sqrt n$ divisions.

What is fatal (and what lots of people get wrong) is to stop too early. If you do that, the problem is typically that squares of primes are falsely recognised as primes. For example, if you divide $19^2$ by the numbers i = 2 to 18 only, you miss the prime factor 19 and falsely identify $19^2$ as a prime. My very first program to list prime numbers displayed the number 121 :-( You got that right, so your code is correct.

One improvement is to avoid dividing n by so many non-primes. You divide by 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 for example. But n cannot be divisible by 4 or 6 because you would have stopped when you divide by 2. So you can divide by 2, and then by odd numbers starting with 3 (3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, ...). That saves about half the divisions. You can get another 33% improvement by dividing by 2, 3, and then the numbers 6k-1 and 6k+1, that is (5, 7), (11, 13), (17, 19) and so on. The numbers of the form 6k+3 are all divisible by 3 and would have been filtered out at the very beginning. You need only one test for each pair of two numbers to check if they are too large, you may do one division too many, but you save one comparison for every two divisions.

You should always test your code. Good tests are the numbers 0 to 10 (0 and 1 are not prime but also not composite), primes obviously, squares or cubes of primes.

Comment: The general case of "avoiding non-primes" is known as wheel factorisation. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_factorization